# why std::function that store a call to member function can have two different callable type

Tags: c++, methods, callable

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int num) : num_(num) {}
    void print_add(int i) const { std::cout << num_+i << '\n'; }
    int num_;
};

int main ()
{
    function<void(const Foo*, int)> func = &Foo::print_add;
    function<void(const Foo&, int)> func2 = &Foo::print_add;
    Foo f(1), f2(2);
    func(&f, 2);
    func2(f2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

why `func` and `func2` both can call member function `Foo::print_add` correctly? they have different callable type as template argument. From what I know,  ‘this’ pointer is passed as a hidden argument to all nonstatic member function calls, the callable type of func2 recieve `const Foo&` as argument which doesn't match the type of `this` pointer. why the code above doesn't generate a compiler error?

Comment: func will store a const pointer internally, func2 will store a const reference internally. Both are valid and both the reference and the pointer are initialized by taking an address (the & operator). There is probably someone around that can explain it in better standardeze though ;)

Comment: `func(&f, 2)` is like `(&f)->print_add(2)`, `func2(f2, 3)` is like `f2.print_add(3)`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but `std::function` may use the [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) mechanism.

Comment: @Eljay The standard does not mandate `std::function` to use `std::invoke` but the specification for the call operator on `std::function` is very similar to the one for `std::invoke` and uses `INVOKE`, which is an operation the standard defines for Callable object.

Comment: @Eljay `std::function` is defined in terms of the (ficticious) `INVOKE` expression, which is reified as `std::invoke`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::function` stores and can ["invoke any CopyConstructible Callable target"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

The [Callable named requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) is defined as follows:

> ```
>  if f is a pointer to member function of class T: 
>
>     If std::is_base_of<T, std::remove_reference_t<decltype(t1)>>::value
>     is true, then INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN) is equivalent to
>     (t1.*f)(t2, ..., tN)
> ```

Or, in other words: if after removing any reference qualifier on the first parameter the end result is the member function's class (or a subclass), the member function gets invoked for the instance of the class.

> ```
> otherwise, if t1 does not satisfy the previous items,
> then INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN) is equivalent to
> ((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN).
> ```

Otherwise: cross your fingers, hope that the first parameter is a pointer to an instance of the member function's class, and invoke it via the given pointer (hoping against hope that it's a pointer, or something that pretends that it's a pointer).

Final results: either one is equivalent to the other.

Comment: "hope that the first parameter is a pointer" or something with an `operator*`, like `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: The one taking a `const Foo&` is extra fun since it can be used to create a temporary `Foo` and invoke on that. So `func2(10, 20);` is also valid although it may look confusing.

Answer (score 2):

> why func and func2 both can call member function Foo::print_add correctly?

They can because standard says that they can.

> From what I know, ‘this’ pointer is passed as a hidden argument

From the language perspective, there is no "hidden pointer passed". A function is called "on" an object and `this` is simply a keyword that produces pointer to that object. Considering the notation `not_a_pointer.member_function(other_arguments)` there appears to be no pointer being passed syntactically.

Underneath the languge, from the implementation perspective (i.e. where "hidden" things are passed), there isn't a difference in the code that references and pointers produce. They're just memory addresses.

---

As an aside: It would be much more convenient if `this` produced a reference rather than a pointer. To my understanding, member functions and `this` were added to the language before references were added, so at that point reference wasn't an option. And afterwards, such change to the language would be backward incompatible.